# Is this question really "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441729/asp-net-mvc-2-dropdownlist-selected-value-property-is-not-coping) as "too localized," since it referred to an extremely old version of jQuery, but my flag was declined (no evidence found).

I assumed that, since this question's accepted answer referenced a bug (that has subsequently been closed with a fix (although the final message is somewhat confusing on that bug report, there is a deep copy function that appears to have made it into future versions of jQuery), and is a bug I can't reproduce in IE8 as of [jQuery revision 1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/9HSUJ/1/)) on the jQuery site itself, that qualified it as too localized.

Did I incorrectly flag this question, or was this just a simple mistake?

Comment: Wondering now if this question is too localized, given that flag weight has no impact on the user (except in terms of priorities of their flag in the queue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117192/140951) is the reason that I rejected the flag, but it was a mistake on my part to not have followed through on the bug report.

In seeing that the version of jQuery was *not* included in the question (at [the time I was resolving the flag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5441729/3)), the assumption was that this was relatively recent.

That was a mistake on my part, as I should have followed the link to investigate exactly what version the bug was for, performed the edit, and then closed as too localized.

I apologize for the effect this has had on your flag weight.

The question has been closed as "too localized", given the edits to reflect the version of jQuery that this occurs in.

Comment: No problem whatsoever. I assumed that the link to the bug report was enough for "too localized," but this discussion provides me with a much better sense of awareness when it comes to questions like that one.

Comment: @jwiscarson: Quite honestly, the link in itself should have been enough.  Granted, it's always *helpful* to moderators when as much information as possible is pointed out to them, but it's not a requirement; the duty falls on the moderator to investigate as thoroughly as possible when investigating a flag, and I clearly failed to do that here.

Comment: I often have a hard time deciding between "Other" and providing my own explanation or using a built-in reason. Regardless, I fully appreciate that all of you have very difficult jobs, and don't begrudge human error or minor oversight for one second.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you "flagged a question as too localized" I'm guessing you made a flag for a custom reason. Anyway *voting to close as localized* is defined as:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

I don't believe the question you linked fits those criteria, *as long as the version of jQuery being used is edited into the question*. As it stands right now, the question *is* too localized because it refers to a specific moment in time. Adding the version locks down the question to a specific version of jQuery. Others may find it helpful because (oh the horror) they are not able to update to the latest version of the library.

There's a big difference between a question using a library version that's very old and a question that's localized.

I've added the version of jQuery I suspect the asker was using (based on the answer) to the question.

<del>All that aside, I still would have just cast a close vote on the question and let (4) others help decide whether or not the question was too localized, rather than flag the question.</del>

Comment: He does not have enough reputation to cast close votes, so he has to raise a flag instead.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Ah, okay. Good point, I should have checked that.

Comment: I added the link to the jsfiddle to note that you wouldn't even have to have the latest version. It appears to have only been a bug prior to 1.3.2, and that's why I flagged it the way I did. Nonetheless, your point is well taken and something I'll bear in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider that question too localized.

Yeah, the number of folks who might encounter that problem is small, and getting smaller all the time... But it's hardly inconceivable that some might still find the question and its answer useful. Indeed, as memory of the problem fades, those still effected by it may well find it harder to find solutions.

What you could have done instead is what Andrew Whitaker has now done: edit the question or the answer to clarify the source of the bug. This avoids the red herring for users who encounter some other, similar, issue and find this question.